# PNG image discoloration when printed on background color

Tags: html, css, image, transparency

I am trying to print a div with an image (logo size), on a background color that spans the width of the page.

The background color should be the same as the background color of the image, and on the screen, it appears fine, however, when I go to print the page, it prints a nice weird border around the png, and the background color of the image is discolored.

I've tried this using different browsers, and I think I removed the gamma information from the image, yet the problem persists.

Any leads on what may cause this and how to resolve this issue?

```
 <div class="main" style="background-color: #222">
      <img src="image.png"/> <!-- background color of image is also #222 as created in GIMP, it used to have a transparent background, but I was getting differences with background as a transparent image as well...-->
 </div>
```

I think this has to do with some image transparency settings the image has stored, as the problem is identical whether the image is 'transparent' or is saved with a background color.

I don't know the history of the image, as I didn't create it; I think ideally, if I can maintain its transparent background, that would be best, but I'd like for it to print cleanly with a background color.

[image: JPG with like color background. Appears normal on my screen, but can see where the image starts and ends upon print.]

Comment: I expect it does have to do with the Alpha layer. I would recommend saving it as, say, a jpeg and try again. You may even be able to convert it back to a png after saving it as a jpeg to get rid of the transparency. Just speaking off the top of my head right now, completely guessing here

Comment: I just tried a jpg conversion in gimp...same problem...=/

Comment: How did you do the conversion? Did you try simply saving it as a different file type (not doing an actual conversion)? Try opening the PNG in Paint, go to Save As... and save it as a jpeg.

Comment: i used thge save as option. Then I tried copying and pasting to a new canvas, then saving as a jpg. I think I'm ultimately going to abandon this and just create an image 'banner', as I'm having cross browser compatibility issues with this method anyway... =/

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to your original post of what the image looks like on the background?

Comment: Added. Though the reason I'm moving towards the banner image option is because firefox and IE don't support printing backgrounds unless the user selects it/defines it in their browser. This is not ideal for creating a printable report...images are more likely to be guaranteed to print, so I think an image banner will have to be the way to go.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. You are trying to get rid of the lighter-colored box around the "star", no? You might try opening the original image in photoshop and get rid of the background completely (make it transparent), and then add the new png (just the "star") to the webpage.

Comment: Yep, that's the 'problem'. This happens when the background is transparent too (started with a transparent png). But so far, I've only tested this in the Chrome browser (as IE and Firefox require allowing a setting of printing background images/colors, so I haven't been testing it in IE and Firefox, but for that reason, I'm thinking of just creating a 'full banner' instead of trying to overlay a transparent logo on top of a printable background color)

Comment: I see. I'm afraid I won't be of much help here, I've never had this issue before. Hopefully someone else can offer some better insight. Good luck!